# How do I take onwership of my DVD (PC)

Tags: windows-10, windows-xp, dvd

I hooked on in my old drives from an xp machine that was in storage. I don't have permission to access the xp system drive, but that is sorted out through security settings.

However, my new DVD drive can't be renamed because I don't have permission apparently. And that thing doesn't have a security tab ;)

Is it possible the new DVD is somehow being associated as owned by the old XP user thus lacking access on my new machine?

---

Because I'm hooking up 3 more DVDs and everybody has to be able to identify them specifically beyond drive letter.

Anyway here's how.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\DriveIcons\F\DefaultLabel
```

Got to regedit and add subkeys to DriveIcons for any drive you want to label. My current DVD is F. So at DriveIcons an F key is created and inside that make a DefaultLabel key. Edit the default string there and that will be your label.

I guess you have to remember that you did that because this is an override and even if I change devices and F becomes a hdd its still going to carry that label unless you remember to delete these keys when changing drives.

Comment: Unlikely a security issue. How are you trying to "rename" your DVD drive? Why?

Comment: Welcome to [su]! I have converted your answer to an edit. Please bear in mind that this is not a conventional forum. We allow users to [edit] their questions to clarify or add details as the area below the question is intended only for answers. Please consider taking the [tour] to see how things work here.

Comment: DriveIcons (This is where I used to add 'DefaultIcon' to the specific drive). I didn't like XP's hardware drive icons, so I added my own.

Answer (score 3):

- The **name** of the a DVD Volume is determined by the UDF or ISO9660 volume label. Since you can't change those, you also can't change the name.
- The **drive letter** is defined via computer administration (assigne or change drive letter), which you can access via right click in Storage Administration (the `diskmgmt.msc` tool).